# Leitura de arquivo Excel

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando usar o **C#** para ler um arquivo Excel, mas toda vez que que executo o código a última coluna não é armazenada

Código de Leitura:

```
        //Cria conexão com a planilha
        OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + caminhoParaOArquivo + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';");
        //Cria um Adapter para executar o comando Select
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Result$]", conexao);
        //Cria um DataSet para armazenar os dados da consulta
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Abre a conexão
        conexao.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
```

O arquivo que estou tentando ler tem seis colunas, quando executo esse código, só são armazenadas no **DataSet** 5 colunas.
Já procurei diversas maneiras de fazer a mesma coisa e sempre dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: nenhum, faz todo o processo sem acusar erro nenhum, mas no final não traz todas as informações do arquivo excel

Answer (score 2):

Refiz seu exemplo com o driver JET, se você puder usá-lo.

```
string cnnString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""", caminhoParaOArquivo);
string isql = "select * from [Result$]";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cnnString);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(isql, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```